# I want to create dynamic select option list using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-select

I have 3 arrays: one for the value, and 2<sup>nd</sup> one for the option name, and the third one for the price.

I want to create a dynamic option list using value and option name (value is channel id and channel name) and, on selection of the channel name, display the sum of the price of the channel in the other textbox.

I am using the below to display the dynamic option name:

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber4"); 
        var options = channel;
         console.log(options);

         $('#selectNumber4').html('');

        for( option in options ) {
        select.add( new Option( options[option]) );
    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically add elements via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935533/how-to-dynamically-add-elements-via-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Drop-Down list (<select>) programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001961/how-to-add-drop-down-list-select-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply try following

```js
var select = $("<select></select>");
var chanels = ["chanel1", "chanel2", "chanel3"]
var chanelValue = ["1", "2", "3"]

for(var i=0;i<chanels.length;i++){
  var option = $("<option></option>");
  $(option).val(chanelValue[i]);
  $(option).html(chanels[i]);
  $(select).append(option);
}

$(".default").append(select);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="default">
<div>
```

Comment: nos of array is dynamic for key/value (channel_id,channel_name)

Comment: And also i want to show price on select of channel in text box